# looping through table to hide button in repeater

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms, repeater

I have a dataset full of records, I want for all those that exist in this dataset, to hide my `LinkButton` in the ASP.NET `Repeater`, what am I doing wrong here?

C#:

```
protected void Page_PreRender(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var getOperator = _administrationSystem.GetOperatorsInformation(userId); //Dataset
    if (rptAdd.Items.Count > 0) //rptAdd is a Repeater
    {
        for (var count = 0; count < rptAdd.Items.Count; count++)
        {
            var btnSubmit = (LinkButton)rptAdd.Items[count].FindControl("btnSubmitOperator");

            foreach (var attendants in getOperator.Tables[0].Rows)
            {
                btnSubmit.Visible = attendants != null;
            }
        }
    }
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

> i want for all those that exists in this dataset, to hide my linkbutton
>
> btnSubmit.Visible = attendants != null;

if attendant is not null (attendant exists), set btnSubmit to visible

But your post sounds more like you want to hide the button if an attendant exists:

```
btnSubmit.Visible = attendants == null;
```

Comment: then it is most likely your foreach loop, it is unlikely that var attendants would be null, what does getOperator.Tables[0].Rows return?

Comment: The problem is that I am comparing 2 tables, table A and table B have same records, I want if table A has records in it, table B should filter out the buttons...

Comment: Then you need to update your code and question to paint the whole picture, at the moment we are only seeing part of it. Where is table A, where is table B, what information do they have in them, etc.